# Поиск идущих подряд одинаковых символов в строке

Tags: java, парсер, текст

Помогите поправить цикл.

Нужно найти подстроку максимальной длины, состоящую из одного и того же символа идущего подряд.

Например, есть строка **"acccabcfbbffffffcccc"**, нужно вывести число 6, потому что *ffffff* - это максимальная подстрока.

Сделать надо одним циклом.

Начало такое:

```
 public static int getMaxCharInSubstring(String inputString) {
        if (inputString.isEmpty()) {
            return -1;
        }
        int countCharsInSubString = 0;
        int countCharsInSubStringTemp = 0;
        inputString = inputString.toUpperCase();
        for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length() - 1; ++i) {

            if (inputString.charAt(i) == inputString.charAt(i + 1)) {
                countCharsInSubStringTemp +=1;
                ++i;

                if (countCharsInSubStringTemp > countCharsInSubString) {
                    countCharsInSubString = countCharsInSubStringTemp;
                }
            }
        }

        return countCharsInSubString;

    }
```

Comment: Что с началом не так?

Comment: Ваш код не работает? Работает, но не так? Выдает не тот результат, который ожидается? Опишите подробнее свою проблему.

Answer (score 7):

Если использовать регулярное выражение, то получится очень красивый и простой алгоритм:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "acccabcfbbffffffcccc";
        int maxLen = 0;

        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.)\\1+").matcher(text);
        while (m.find()) {
            String sub = m.group();
            System.out.println(sub);

            if (sub.length() > maxLen) {
                maxLen = sub.length();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nmaxLen: " + maxLen);
    }
}
```

Консоль:

```
ccc
bb
ffffff
cccc

maxLen: 6
```

---

Регулярка `(.)\\1+` говорит о том, что ищем любой символ, после которого сразу идет 1 или больше таких же символов

Answer (score 1):

Проблема у вас была в условии. Проверяем, если символ равен следующему символу буфер `countCharsInSubStringTemp` увеличиваем на 1, но как только мы определили, что следующий символ не равен предыдущему, то делается проверка `countCharsInSubString< countCharsInSubStringTemp`, если так, то устанавливаем максимальное количество символов равное `countCharsInSubStringTemp` и  обнуляем:

```
public static int getMaxCharInSubstring(String inputString) {
            if (inputString.isEmpty()) {
                return -1;
            }
            int countCharsInSubString = 0;
            int countCharsInSubStringTemp = 0;
            inputString = inputString.toUpperCase();
            int length = inputString.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (inputString.charAt(i) == inputString.charAt(i + 1)) {
                    countCharsInSubStringTemp +=1;
                 }else
                    if (countCharsInSubStringTemp > countCharsInSubString) {
                        countCharsInSubString = countCharsInSubStringTemp;
                        countCharsInSubStringTemp=0;
                    }
                }
            }
            return countCharsInSubString;
        }
```

Comment: Чем тебе мой ответ не нравится?

Comment: Это мне не понравился. Комментариев нет, объяснений что было неправильно и что изменилось тоже нет. Бесполезный ответ.

Comment: Еще и вредный. Не нужно в определении цикла использовать функции.

Comment: @Эникейщик я подправил автора. это уже пусть он сам разбирается, алгоритм простой. не вижу смысла его объяснять. И да, эту задачу я бы решил с помощью регулярных выражений.

Comment: @Эникейщик подправил, прошу изменить вашу оценку

Answer (score 0):

Получилось так:

```
 int countCharsInSubString = 0;
    int countCharsInSubStringTemp = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length() - 1; ++i) {
        if (inputString.charAt(i) == inputString.charAt(i + 1)) {
            countCharsInSubStringTemp += 1;
        } else if (countCharsInSubStringTemp > countCharsInSubString) {
            countCharsInSubString = countCharsInSubStringTemp;
            countCharsInSubStringTemp = 0;
        }
    }
    if (countCharsInSubStringTemp > countCharsInSubString) {
        return (countCharsInSubStringTemp + 1);
    } else return (countCharsInSubString + 1);
}
```